# How to define an instance attribute in a pandas DataFrame subclass?

Tags: python, pandas, object

I am subclassing pandas DataFrame and I want to have an attribute.

```
class MyFrame(pd.DataFrame):


    _metadata = ['myattr']
    myattr = []


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pd.DataFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.myattr.append(0)


    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return AutoData
```

My issue is that `myattr` is a class attribute. When I modify it in an instance of my class, every instances got modified:

```
mf2 = mf
mf2.myattr.append(1)
print(mf.myattr)
>>> [0, 1]
```

But I want the attribute to be attached with its instance. In other word, modify `myattr` only for `mf2` but not for `mf`. Thank you.

Comment: You can simply define attribute in `__init__` **self.myattr = []**, by this you are sure this is instance's attribute ;)

Comment: Yes but then  it raises 2 issues: (1) `myattr` will not be attached to copies of my object and (2) it gives this warning: _UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name_

Comment: Well, I don't know how much this will be problematic for you but consider creating class which will not inherit from DataFrame but instead will contain it as for example `self.df = pd.DataFrame`. Composition in this case looks like better solution because it will not need from you to adjust to DataFrame implementation at cost of wrapping it. Of course this isn't best solution at all cases but still, consider it :)

Comment: Thank you for you advice. I finally manage to find a solution by defining the attribute in `__init__` and redefining the `copy` method which now copy also my attribute to the new DataFrame. Then I use `copy()` to duplicate my object.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning instance attributes to a pd.DataFrame subclass can be done as following:

```
class MyFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    _metadata = ['myattr']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pd.DataFrame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.myattr = [0]

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyFrame
```

The `_metadata` list sets the attributes that should not be considered as columns. Names listed in `_metadata` are considered in the `__setattr__()` and `__getattr__()` methods of the parentclass of `pd.DataFrame`(which is `NDFrame`) and set as object attributes without raising the *UserWarning*.

While `_metadata` are normal properties there is also the possibility to set temporary properties with `_internal_names` as described in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-subclassing-pandas). Temporary properties are not kept after dataframe modifictions.